# Sum consecutive numbers in a String of integers

Tags: algorithm

I need to write a function when given a String of integers, it returns a String of integers where all consecutive integers are replaced with the sum of those integers.

**For example:**

When given: `String = "144404331"` the function returns `"40461"`. You might think it would be `"1120461"` however we need to *continue* the process until there are *no consecutive digits*.

My solution to this is extremely long and was wondering if anyone had a recursive / intuitive solution that could be completed in a reasonable amount of time.

**Method header:**

```
String consecutiveSum(String number) {}
```

Comment: So are consecutive digits or integers are to be replaced by their sum? For example, if "1212" is an input should the output be "24" or "1212"? Also, you should post what you've tried so far so that we can give better advice/hints for an improved solution instead of giving away the answer outright.

Comment: @wLui155 1212 would output "1212".

Comment: does "8444" map to "812" or "164"?

Comment: could you define better by what do you mean consecutive integers? what takes priority to merge if you have multiple options? and could we see what you tried? what the complexity you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use *recursive* solution e.g. (**c# code**):

```
    private static string consecutiveSum(string text)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);

        bool wantRecursiveCall = false;
        char prior = '\0';
        int sum = -1;

        foreach (var c in text)
        {
            if (c != prior)
            {
                if (sum >= 0)
                    sb.Append(sum);

                sum = 0;
            }
            else
                wantRecursiveCall = true;

            sum += c - '0';
            prior = c;
        }

        sb.Append(sum);

        return wantRecursiveCall ? consecutiveSum(sb.ToString()) : sb.ToString();
    }
```